# git: detach head and force overwrite

Tags: git, branch, commit

I normally work my way around git but this time it's bugging me! I am on a certain branch which had lets say 3 commits since its creation (i.e. `001`, `002`, `003`). So as I was on `003` I checked out to `002` and made some changes which I then commited to `002` now I want to overwrite my branch with the new commit, making it the head of the branch.

I tried to push and I got the following `git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>`. So I then tried to `git push origin HEAD:my-branch` and it got rejected (without even being sure if this is what I should be doing).

Any ideas on how to work around it?

Comment: vote down and not even a comment! Good Job nawb!

Comment: When you checked out `002`, was it on a new branch? I assume, it was not. Hence, `HEAD` is in detached state. If yes, that branch doesn't know what is it's remote repo (or origin), right? What would you like to achieve with the new commit (let's call it `004`)?

Comment: @Bhaskar Yes! It is as you described it. So what I was trying to do is set that detached head as the head of the branched I checked out from. So the end result would be something like reset all changes from last commit on the branch ie `003` (making `002` the head of the branch), making some changes and then commiting again.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your push got rejected because you had already pushed `003` to the server repository and your local branch had changes on top of `002` with `003` removed (if I understand correctly)

You can try to force the push and overwrite the remote (if that's REALLY what you want to do) with the `--force` option to `git push`.  ie:

```
git push --force
```

I recommend making the appropriate backups if you are going to use the `--force` option if you're not sure of what you're doing...

Comment: yep thought of it but wasnt really sure if i should `force`

Comment: if you're looking to change the existing history on the remote, that's the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I ll back up and give it a go. will accept answer if it works!

Comment: just used the backup and commit again on the head of my branch... can't find another way

Answer (score 1):

```
git push -f origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

will override your remote branch with your local one, setting tip to your current detached HEAD.

Answer (score -1):

State of local repo after `git clone`:

```
001----002----003 HEAD/master
```

When you checked out `002` and made some changes and committed it, the state is:

```
001----002----003 master
        \
         +----004 HEAD/detached branch
```

What you want is either this: (a)

```
001----002------005----003 HEAD/master
        \      /
         +----004 detached branch
```

Or, this: (b)

```
   001----002----003----004 HEAD/master
```

In above case `005` will be a merge commit.

I assume it is NOT (b) because the point of checking out `002` makes no sense in that case. If it's (a) you have to:

1. checkout master from detached branch.
2. merge the detached branch in to master.

If you rebase, instead of merge in step 2, then history will be linear and, IMO, clean, like this:

```
   001----002----004----003 HEAD/master
```

Will this solve your concern?